# How do I take the slack out of a door closer chain?

Tags: doors, door-frame, fire-safety, chain, closer

There is a cylinder with a spring inside. Presumably when the spring is compressed it will pull the external chain attached to it to be taught, I.e. not slack.

But I can't keep the spring compressed to then insert it back into the door cavity and faceplate on top.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a sketch of what I mean by the spring inside the cylinder.

[image]

Comment: is the spring compressed when not connected to anything?

Comment: if the spring is as illustrated in your diagram, then the top picture should show a tensioned chain .... you are missing something ... the rectangular cutout in the door edge indicates that you are missing at least one piece

Comment: Thank you @jsotola with regard to the missing part. I will consider carefully disassembling same mechanism on another working door to see what that missing part could be. I had disassembled the original door to be able to manoeuvre furniture and may well be able to identify that part in the same box where I stored the cylinder, after comparing with the working door.

Comment: To answer your question is the spring compressed when not connected to anything. Answer is no. But when I push a screwdriver into the end of the cylinder I can feel the tension of the spring compressed.

Comment: then you probably drew the diagram incorrectly ... the spring probably compresses when you pull the chain

Comment: +1 jsotola thank you, now that's a thought! Maybe I connected it up wrong or there's a missing part as you say.

Comment: take pictures when you are disassembling anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I need to twist the chain to increase the tension, according to this Q&A: [How to stop self closing doors from slamming](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/77121/3318)

Thanks to jsotola for their input.

There is another faceplate, which I had while working on this, but not shown in photograph. But, as jsotola suggests, I should check for other missing parts.

Key things:

- I was putting it in the wrong way around.
- Need to use a chain stopper, clip to hold chain while fitting.

This video was key to my understanding too: https://youtu.be/P5SalSwsigc

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]